# Why does Linq allow accidental comparison assignments?

Tags: c#, linq

Unlike C and C++, when you do this in C#

```
bool b = true;
if(b = false) Console.WriteLine("Dont panic!");
```

The compiler (rightfully) complains `Warning CS0665 Assignment in conditional expression is always constant; did you mean to use == instead of = ?`

However, if I accidentally assign instead of compare inside a Linq statement, there's no warning whatsoever and the compiler compiles:

```
var list = new List<bool>() { true, false, true };
var count = list.Count(b => b = false); //returns 0
Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Decompile shows what the Lambda looks like:

```
internal bool <Main>b__0_0(bool b) => false;
```

It's even worse when you use an object:

```
var count = list.Count(s => s.SomeField = false); //returns 0

internal bool <Main>b__0_0(Program.Stuff s)
{
    bool flag;
    s.SomeField = flag = false;
    return flag;
}
```

Is there a reason the compiler doesn't prevent this?

Comment: There are legitimate use cases for lambdas with side effects. Unlike your `if` example, the compiler cannot see that this particular use of assignment *almost certainly* should have been a comparison (and even so, note that it merely warns); it knows about `if` statements, but not so much about what you really intended to do with that `Enumerable.Count` call. (An argument can be made to warn for a lambda of the form `s => s = value`, since that kind of parameter assignment is a no-op, but even *this* has legitimate uses for expression tree inspection.)

Comment: Note that if you restrict LINQ to "the part of LINQ that's actually part of the language", you'll find that you don't just get a warning, the compiler actually disallows it: `var count = (from b in list where b = false select b).Count();` fails to compile, since you can't assign to range variables. (`let` does not get around this.) For generic lambda use though, no dice.